# Is it possible to get test scores for each iteration of MLPClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I would like to look at the loss curves for training data and test data side by side. Currently it seems straightforward to get the loss on the training set for each iteration using `clf.loss_curve` (See below).

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
clf = MLPClassifier()
clf.fit(X,y)
clf.loss_curve_ # this seems to have loss for the training set
```

However, I would also like to plot performance on a test data set. Is this available?

Answer (score 12):

`clf.loss_curve_` is not part of the [API-docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html#sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier) (although used in some examples). The only reason it's there is because it's used internally for *early-stopping*.

As Tom mentions, there is also some approach to use `validation_scores_`.

Apart from that, more complex setups might need to do a more manual way of training, where you can control when, what and how to measure something.

After reading Tom's answer, it might be wise to say: if only inter-epoch calculations are needed, his approach of combining `warm_start` and `max_iter` saves some code (and uses more of sklearn's original code). This code here could do intra-epoch calculations (if needed; compare with keras) too.

Simple (prototype) example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
np.random.seed(1)

""" Example based on sklearn's docs """
mnist = fetch_mldata("MNIST original")
# rescale the data, use the traditional train/test split
X, y = mnist.data / 255., mnist.target
X_train, X_test = X[:60000], X[60000:]
y_train, y_test = y[:60000], y[60000:]

mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(50,), max_iter=10, alpha=1e-4,
                    solver='adam', verbose=0, tol=1e-8, random_state=1,
                    learning_rate_init=.01)

""" Home-made mini-batch learning
    -> not to be used in out-of-core setting!
"""
N_TRAIN_SAMPLES = X_train.shape[0]
N_EPOCHS = 25
N_BATCH = 128
N_CLASSES = np.unique(y_train)

scores_train = []
scores_test = []

# EPOCH
epoch = 0
while epoch < N_EPOCHS:
    print('epoch: ', epoch)
    # SHUFFLING
    random_perm = np.random.permutation(X_train.shape[0])
    mini_batch_index = 0
    while True:
        # MINI-BATCH
        indices = random_perm[mini_batch_index:mini_batch_index + N_BATCH]
        mlp.partial_fit(X_train[indices], y_train[indices], classes=N_CLASSES)
        mini_batch_index += N_BATCH

        if mini_batch_index >= N_TRAIN_SAMPLES:
            break

    # SCORE TRAIN
    scores_train.append(mlp.score(X_train, y_train))

    # SCORE TEST
    scores_test.append(mlp.score(X_test, y_test))

    epoch += 1

""" Plot """
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax[0].plot(scores_train)
ax[0].set_title('Train')
ax[1].plot(scores_test)
ax[1].set_title('Test')
fig.suptitle("Accuracy over epochs", fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Or a bit more compact:

```
plt.plot(scores_train, color='green', alpha=0.8, label='Train')
plt.plot(scores_test, color='magenta', alpha=0.8, label='Test')
plt.title("Accuracy over epochs", fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Using `MLPClassifier(early_stopping=True)`, the stopping criterion changes from the training loss to the accuracy score, which is computed on a validation set (whose size is controlled by the parameter `validation_fraction`).

The validation score of each iteration is stored inside `clf.validation_scores_`.

Another possibility is to use `warm_start=True` with `max_iter=1`, and to compute manually all the quantity you want to monitor after each iteration.