# How can I get the train and test scores for each iteration of a MLPRegressor?

Tags: scikit-learn, training-data, loss-function

This answer seems exactly what I need BUT for a regressor instead of a classifier.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46913459/9726897

I made very minor modifications to modified the code provided by sascha from link as shown below.  I thought it would be fairly straightforward to use for my MLPRegressior... but I'm getting an error message I don't know how to fix  Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor


estimator_reg = MLPRegressor(
    solver='adam',
    activation='relu',
    learning_rate='adaptive',
    learning_rate_init=.01,
    hidden_layer_sizes=[100],
    alpha=0.01,
    max_iter=1000,
    random_state=42,
    tol=0.0001,
    early_stopping=False,
    warm_start=True,
    beta_1=0.7,
    beta_2=0.98,
    epsilon=0.0000000001,
    verbose=10,
)

""" Home-made mini-batch learning
    -> not to be used in out-of-core setting!
"""
N_TRAIN_SAMPLES = train_data.shape[0]
N_EPOCHS = 25
N_BATCH = 128


scores_train = []
scores_test = []

# EPOCH
epoch = 0
while epoch < N_EPOCHS:
    print('epoch: ', epoch)
    # SHUFFLING
    random_perm = np.random.permutation(train_data.shape[0])
    mini_batch_index = 0
    while True:
        # MINI-BATCH
        indices = random_perm[mini_batch_index:mini_batch_index + N_BATCH]
        estimator_reg.partial_fit(train_data[indices], train_labels[indices])
        mini_batch_index += N_BATCH

        if mini_batch_index >= N_TRAIN_SAMPLES:
            break

    # SCORE TRAIN
    scores_train.append(estimator_reg.score(train_data, train_labels))

    # SCORE TEST
    scores_test.append(estimator_reg.score(test_data, test_labels))

    epoch += 1

""" Plot """
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax[0].plot(scores_train)
ax[0].set_title('Train')
ax[1].plot(scores_test)
ax[1].set_title('Test')
fig.suptitle("Accuracy over epochs", fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

and I get this error: 
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
---> 46         estimator_reg.partial_fit(train_data[indices], train_labels[indices])
.......
.......
KeyError: '[ 789 1493  353   33 1011 2029 1696 1649  653 1648   22 2477 2120 1000\n 2481 2448 1704 1962 2291 1995 2085  710  967 1839  461  504 1650 2166\n  584  513  676 1196 1621 2109  766 2012 1017 1636 1286  448 2049 1791\n  141 1168 1249  159 2061 2456  431 1799 2249 2379 1169 1044 1010  120\n 2503  316 1070  671 1005 2164  975 2371  811 1555 1193 1316  487 1867\n 1262 1395  135 2224   32 1509 2132  997  263  233 1614 2317 1432   49\n 1251 2227 2536 1955  359  650 2287  792 1900  606  763 1837  742  965\n 1190   53  910 2486  738  103 1965   99 1084  123 1061  806  384 2261\n 2284 2114  360 1075 1479 1446  455 2294  221 1856  979 1078 2106  189\n 2153 1183] not in index'

Comment: What is the type of your train data? is it a numpy array? a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: It is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: I guess that you have indexes that are not in the range (0,N_TRAIN_SAMPLES). That may happen if you deleted or filtered some rows. Try changing this line `random_perm = np.random.permutation(train_data.shape[0])` into this `random_perm = np.random.permutation(train_data.index.values)` .

Comment: That was the issue Quasi - Thanks!!

Comment: I'll add an answer so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you have indexes that are not in the range (0,`N_TRAIN_SAMPLES`).
That may happen if you deleted or filtered some rows, or the index contained from the begining some numbers not in that range.

Try changing this line:

```
random_perm = np.random.permutation(train_data.shape[0])
```

into this:

```
random_perm = np.random.permutation(train_data.index.values)
```