# How to visualize model training history using scikit learn's MLP classifier?

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, curve, mlp

I have used the pima-indians-diabetes.csv dataset. I have built a neural network containing architecture 12-8-1 using Keras and I was able to visualize the training history perfectly. Next, I tried to implement the same model using MLPCLassifier from scikit learn. Is it possible to implement training history curves in this case like I did with Keras? I just need to visualize my training history, that is, training accuracy, validation accuracy, training loss and validation loss, like I did with Keras. My code and curves using Keras:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
import numpy
numpy.random.seed(42)

# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("/content/gdrive/My Drive/pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, kernel_initializer= 'uniform' , activation= 'relu' ))
model.add(Dense(8, kernel_initializer= 'uniform' , activation= 'relu' ))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer= 'uniform' , activation= 'sigmoid' ))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss= 'binary_crossentropy' , optimizer= 'adam' , metrics=[ 'accuracy' ])

history= model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.33, epochs=150, batch_size=10)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history[ 'accuracy' ])
plt.plot(history.history[ 'val_accuracy' ])
plt.title( 'model accuracy' )
plt.ylabel( 'accuracy' )
plt.xlabel( 'epoch' )
plt.legend([ 'train' , 'test' ], loc= 'lower right' )
plt.show()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history[ 'loss' ])
plt.plot(history.history[ 'val_loss' ])
plt.title( 'model loss' )
plt.ylabel( 'loss' )
plt.xlabel( 'epoch' )
plt.legend([ 'train' , 'test' ], loc= 'upper left' )
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

My code using sklearn's MLP classifier:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

#Using MLPclassifier from sklearn
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

clf1 = MLPClassifier(batch_size=10, max_iter=150, hidden_layer_sizes=(12, 8), verbose=True, 
early_stopping=True, random_state=42)

clf1.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
#Predicting y for X_val
y_pred = clf1.predict(X_test)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

I was able to generate a classification report but no graphical visualization. How can I generate curves like those attached using sklearn's MLPClassifier like I did with Keras?

Comment: Careful, validation and test sets are two very different concepts and you should be clear about the differences first. Validation will give you a history, test won't. In your sklearn code, you're not really validating after each epoch so there won't be any history for validation as you're just testing the final model. For your question, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912557/is-it-possible-to-get-test-scores-for-each-iteration-of-mlpclassifier

Comment: Actually the scikit learn MLPClassifier has an argument, validation fraction which is set to 0.1 i.e, 10% by default. So the model is getting validated after each iteration on 10% of training data. I have attached the link to sklearn's documentation. [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html]