# How to plot training loss from sklearn logistic regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I tried the solution here: [sklearn logistic regression loss value during training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67488908/sklearn-logistic-regression-loss-value-during-training)

With `verbose=0` and `verbose=1`. `loss_history` is nothing, and `loss_list` is empty, although the epoch number and change in loss are still printed in the terminal.

```
Epoch 1, change: 1.00000000
Epoch 2, change: 0.32949890
Epoch 3, change: 0.19452967
Epoch 4, change: 0.14287635
Epoch 5, change: 0.11357212
```

I also tried the solution proposed here: [how to plot correctly loss curves for training and validation sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64516701/how-to-plot-correctly-loss-curves-for-training-and-validation-sets)

I.e., training single epochs iteratively. In this case it doesn't train at all, the loss change is always 1:

```
Epoch 1, change: 1.00000000
max_iter reached after 2 seconds
Epoch 1, change: 1.00000000
max_iter reached after 1 seconds
Epoch 1, change: 1.00000000
max_iter reached after 1 seconds
Epoch 1, change: 1.00000000
max_iter reached after 2 seconds
```

Is there really no straightforward way to do this? I'm totally open to hacky workarounds as well.

My simple code that I want to plot from:

```
logreg = LogisticRegression(
   random_state=42,
   C=.001,
   penalty="l1",
   max_iter=500,
   solver="saga",
   n_jobs=8,
   warm_start=True,
   class_weight='balanced', 
   verbose=1)
 
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only managed a hacky way to solve this, since training iteratively gives different results than a single call to `model.fit` and the workaround mentioned in other solutions using `sys.stdout` unfortunately does not work for the `LogisticRegression()` class, although it does for `SGDClassifier()`.

I run the Python file from the terminal and pipe the output to a file directly:

```
python3 logreg_train.py > terminal_output.txt
```

Then one can parse the text file to extract the change in training loss.

Hope this helps someone!