# Problems plotting loss vs epochs for train and test data in MLPClassifier using sklean

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, neural-network

I saw this code in the community to plot loss vs epochs using MLPClassifier. I think there is something is wrong in the code because the validation curve looks odd. Could someone give me an advice on how to fix the code below?

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split( X,y,test_size=0.2)
mlp=MLPClassifier( validation_fraction=0.2, early_stopping=True, warm_start= True)
mlp.fit(X_train,y_train)



plt.figure()
plt.plot (mlp.loss_curve_, label='Training')
plt.plot(mlp.validation_scores_, label='Validation')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel("Classification score")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are plotting `loss_curve_` which is the loss (error) against `validation_scores_` which are the validation scores for each epoch of training (accuracy) - see [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html).

If you want a 1-1 comparison, you could compare training and validation scores for each epoch by using `partial_fit`, though this may require some additional elbow grease. See: [Is it possible to get test scores for each iteration of MLPClassifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912557/is-it-possible-to-get-test-scores-for-each-iteration-of-mlpclassifier)